# Can I use "stink out" and "stink up" interchangeably in the context of these sentences?

Tags: vocabulary

1. He stank out/up the whole room with his revolting fart stench.
2. The sharp smell of his fart started to stink up/stink out the room.
3. "Eew! His fart stank out/up here!"
4. You must avoid eating dairy products before you go to her wedding. You definitely don’t want to stink up the venue by farting there.
5. Yesterday, during the family reunion, my boyfriend passed gas. And guess what? He actually blamed the unexpected fart on the squeaky chair! What a ridiculous excuse! The foul smell of his fart stuck up/out the dining room the moment he let it out, and he was dumb enough to believe that we would buy his lie.

Can I use them interchangeably in all the sentences above? What's the difference between these two phrasal verbs? When I looked them up in dictionaries, most stated that they are synonyms, meaning "cause to smell bad; fill with a bad smell.''

Answer (score 2):

[ldoceonline](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stink-out#google_vignette) says *out* is used in BrE; and *up*, AmE:

> stink something ↔ **out British English**, stink something ↔ **up American English** phrasal verb
> to fill a place with a very unpleasant smell
> Those onions are stinking the whole house out.

Collins Dictionary also differentiates the phrases in similar manner.

These 2 phrases have the same meaning.